# How to approach signal reconstruction with sampling frequency not equal to reconstruction

Tags: fourier-transform, sampling, dtft, reconstruction

I'm trying to figure out what kind of equations i can use in a situation like this:

[image]

I know the relation between $x(t)$ and $x[n]$ is :

[image]

but then $x[n]$ is multiplied by a pulse train, with a different period than $T_s$.

What kind of relations apply after that operation? What will be the CTFT of that signal?

Comment: Homework questions should be tagged as such. Also hint: Think of the sort of issues that can take place if $T_s < T_r$ or if $T_s > T_r$ and how they relate to the Nyquist rate...

Comment: @AhsanYousaf i understand that Tr basically will determine the width of the LPF. but thats if i look at the signal x[n]*comb as continuous. I dont understand whats the relation between x[n]*comb and its CTFT ... because unlike multiplying x(t) with a pulse train, x[n] is discrete..